# Is an "is this correct" question appropriate for StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

A recent example: [Extension Methods in C# - Is this correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034439/extension-methods-in-c-is-this-correct)

I don't necessarily have a problem per se, but it does strike as something out of bounds. The answer is either yes or no. In fact, if the answer *was* no, that would be better, because then there would be something to correct (and therefore value to add).

I don't know if you close it as off topic or not a real question, but it doesn't seem like this is the type of question that belongs on the site, it doesn't fit the overall purpose.

Comment: "Is this correct" questions have always bothered me a little, because they imply that there is *"The One And Only True Way"* to do things, which is seldom the case.

Comment: Side note: That particular question is a "psychotic question": highly upvoted, highly answered, highly criticized, and on the verge of being closed.

Comment: @Rick, it's that type of thing that makes me balk (rightly or wrongly) at any suggestion that there isn't enough question voting. Not labelling this question necessarily, but there are a bunch of uniteresting, unresearched, duplicated questions that get plenty of upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

To me this question looks fine. There is some useful information in the answers which is to say why it's correct.

There are also answer comments that suggest an improvement. I'd have preferred to see a working code example posted to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Fundamentally this question is a non subjective programming related question which has a supporting well formatted code.

I'd say it is on topic.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I don't have a *strong* stance on this, but here are a few points that have been banging around my head on the issue:

- As Robert already mentioned in a comment, these questions seem to suggest (often incorrectly) that there is just one way to do things.
- Given the above, questions like these therefore have the potential to devolve into a list of answers of the form "Your way is (correct|incorrect), (explanation)... but here's the way I like to do it..." Since this can involve opinion and personal coding preference, it *could* steer things in a subjective and open-ended direction.
- The question can be very localized to the specific problem or code instance, making it less useful for others who come along.
- It sometimes smacks of laziness. In other words, it should be easy for the poster to tell if the code functions correctly or not: run it with a number of test inputs!

All that said, I *suppose* certain questions like this may be useful. If the problem and the code solution are laid out clearly, and the answers keep things objective (i.e. "*This* solution is (provably) faster...", etc.), then other users may get some value from it. However, it seems like questions like this may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).